# How to get rid of latex font on display

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

For the last few hours, whenever I open the https://math.stackexchange.com/ site, the questions are being displayed on latex font in my computer. The problem was not there even  yesterday. I even restarted my computer and reopened the site but the problem persists. Even when I type any questions, the preview option below is not available. Why is that? Please can someone suggest me how to get rid of the problem.

---

**From now-deleted question on the main site:**

> I could not even add a screen shot as the option above the edit portion is not showing.

Comment: Which browser are you using, on which operating system? Did you test whether the problem continues in a different browser? Did you try clearing the cache, or possibly even reinstalling the browser you're using? Does the problem continue if you go to other websites? What if you go to other websites that use MathJax, such as [http://mathoverflow.net/](http://mathoverflow.net/)?

Comment: In your [recent post on the main site](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/541158/264), you said "*I could not even add a screen shot as the option above the edit portion is not showing.*" I don't understand what that means, because that doesn't seem like it's preventing you from taking a screenshot.

Comment: Sir,I wanted to say that the options above the edit portion ( that comes after clicking ""Ask question" ) Links,Images,styling,headers were not shown. Sorry for bad english. I am now checking what you prescribed. Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: I am using google chrome browser with windows 7 os.

Comment: @learner: Do you mean to say that the editing toolbar is not appearing for you?  You should still be able to add images by pressing `<ctrl>+G` when in the editing area.

Comment: I am now using a different browser and the problems I posted is solved. Sorry for bothering you. I apologise for late reply as I have slow internet connection.

Comment: @learner: I wouldn't say that the problem is solved; only that you have found a way around it. If you are still having problems under Chrome it's probably worthwhile to  provide some more information about the problem under Chrome (in particular give the exact version number, and some screenshots of the problem). With the [meta-tag:bug] tag a dev will very likely look into this at some point, and it helps if they know exactly what you are using and what you are seeing. Others may very well be experiencing the same problem. (Also, to respond in comments it helps to `@username` ping them.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer thank you sir for your concern. Now I can open the  stack exchange site on google chrome also. I think the problem was due to very slow internet connection.